# Read (not import) Outlook pst file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have some old Outlook 2003 pst files with a lot of messages (~100k) on a backup drive that I would like to be able to search and read from time to time.  I don't want to import them into my copy of Outlook, since I don't want the clutter.  I see there are some pst readers, but the only ones I can find cost.

What can I do to read and search the pst files without importing them or buying a reader?

I have outlook 2003 and can get 2007 if that will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just Open them, no need to import. File > Open > Outlook Data File

Comment: I was worried open would import them. I can just read, then dismiss without a trace?

Comment: Yes, you can just open them, read, and close them without a trace.  I think you can also open them read-only.  Each one will show up as a separate mailbox in Outlook.  Note that they won't be indexed for fast searching (e.g., Lookout Search, Windows Desktop Search, Google Desktop Search, or Outlook 2007 search) if you only open them as-needed.